# Waiting for fullscreen to complete rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a `svg` element which goes fullscreen by clicking on it. As you know going fullscreen fires `fullscreenchange` events which I used to fix my svg's aspect ratio. I use `$(svgElement).height()` to fetch current height but the problem is that using  `$(svgElement).height()` in `fullscreenchange` event handler can give wrong value especially in mobile browsers.

This might be happening because of fetching size of an element while fullscreen rendering is not complete yet. How can I fix this issue(without using delay)?

Comment: Use the resize event.

Comment: @Kaiido I used  "$(window).on("resize",function)", it works on desktop browsers but when I use it on my nexus 5 chrome, It shows height 568 instead of 640.
It would gave me correct value (640) if I delay the code for 1 second, I wish I could show you in jsfiddle

Comment: ah.. can't test it rn and [specs](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#api) don't require this resize event, so I don't know if it can be called a bug.

Comment: @Kaiido well then I'm forced to use some delay